# Should I say "they" twice in this sentence?

Tags: ellipsis, coordination

I have this sentence:

> Even though some people argue that public transportation systems have many disadvantages, I firmly believe that they have many benefits and **should** be constructed.

Should I put *they* before *should*?

**And why?**

Comment: The phrase "some people" requires "argue" (not "argues"). Did you mean "transportation" instead? The rest is perfectly acceptable as is.

Comment: i mean transportation not transformaton, sorry just a typo. so there is no need for "they" am i right please?

Comment: @Marco - It's "I", not "i". Please remember that. To answer your question, a _they_ is not required before the _should_. I might consider putting a _therefore_ in that spot, though: _I firmly believe that they have many benefits and therefore should be constructed._

Comment: If you want to be fully verbose, "and that they should be constructed". If you want to be terse, "and should be constructed". The intermediate, "and they should be constructed" is also okay. You have your choice of which words to repeat and which to omit. Only the emphasis and style are changed.

Comment: This question now has three answers.  It's a shame we can't vote on any of them.

Comment: @snailboat Now you have something to vote for ;)

Comment: It's ok if you don't add the word "they before should".

Answer (score 2):

> I firmly believe that they have many benefits and they should be constructed.

No, I believe the extra "they" sounds a little wrong here because it is missing the preceding "that". Instead:

> I firmly believe that they have many benefits and that they should be constructed.

However, lets say we believed in many things:

> I believe that it is fun, it is fast, it is exciting and it is crazy.

Or put another way:

> I believe it is fun, fast, exiting and crazy.

Both sentences are completely correct and mean exactly the same thing. However, you would only ever use the first sentence if you really wanted to stress each of the things you believe about the "it". It takes longer time to say, so the listener has longer time to process the information. Normally though you would use the second sentence as there is no need to repeat "it is" again and again as it is clear that we are referring back to the first "it" mentioned.

So, back to your question. Both of these are correct:

> I firmly believe that they have many benefits and should be constructed.
>
> I firmly believe that they have many benefits and that they should be constructed.

but the second sentence places a bit more stress around the end of the sentence, in my opinion. It allows you to emphasis that last "should" in the sentence.

However, having said all that, I would improve this sentence as follows:

> Even though some people argue that public transportation systems have many disadvantages, I firmly believe that they have many benefits and as a result I think they should be constructed.

The "as a result" is making it clearer that it is because of the benefits that they should be built. In your original sentence you are saying simply that you believe in two things:

I believe:

1) they have benefits and

2) they should be constructed.

Finally, here is my version of your sentence:

> There are those of us who argue that public transportation systems have many disadvantages. However, I firmly believe that they have many benefits and it is because of this belief that I think they should be constructed.